How to use Guassian Random timer properly in Jmeter
I am working on one project of load testing where I need to execute the jmeter script for 50000 users. There is an requirement to use guassian random timer to replicate real world scenario.
Previously I achieve this target with constant timer with 120 minutes ramp up. As constant timer are not realistic I need to use guassian random timer.
I attempted by adding guassian timer in my script as per constant timer counter value.
For example. previously I used 5000 sec constant time in one sampler of script. So I added not 5000  constant offset delay and 2000 deviation but still it is not working.
Could you please help me that how to achieve this target by using guassian random timer.
Also gone through one document which states that there are only 68% chance to utilize it properly.

It's not clear what does your "still it is not working" mean.
Gaussian Random Timer will return:

Static delay of 5000 seconds
Plus the value from 0 to the maximum value of the "deviation" got randomly from normal distribution calculated using Marsaglia polar method

So using Gaussian Random Timer will result into lower throughput than for Constant Timer with static delay of 5000 seconds as the think times will be higher.
More information: A Comprehensive Guide to Using JMeter Timers
In order to get better help you need to share:

your current setup
your current throughput
your desired throughput

